# Report Server Review

Tags: sql-server, reportserver

I'm looking at a standard installation of Report Designer in SQL and I'd like to do some analysis on the reports and their usage.

I found a view, [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog], and linked it to My Catalog to see the names of the reports and number of times run.

I'm trying to find 2 things. Reports being used(with count) and reports not being used.

Are the below queries correct? the second one returns no rows which feels very wrong.

```
 SELECT 
       COUNT([ReportID]) as [Reports Run]
       ,[UserName]
      ,C.[Name]
 FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog] E Left Join [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] C on C.[ItemID] = E.[ReportID] 
   Where
   E.[TimeStart] > (SELECT dateadd(month, -3, getdate()))
   Group by  
       [UserName]
      ,[ReportID]
      ,C.[Name]
```

---

```
 Select *, [Name] from [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] C WHERE [Name] not in (Select [Name] FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog])
```

Comment: I am a bit unclear what your question is.  As phrased, this is too broad for a single Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I'm trying to find 2 things. Reports being used(with count) and reports not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you can get the number of times that each item in the *catalog* was referenced in `executionlog` in the past three months -- and `0` if there is no reference:

```
SELECT C.[ItemID],
       SUM(CASE WHEN E.[TimeStart] > DATEADD(MONTH, -3, getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as times_in_3_months
FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] C LEFT JOIN
     [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog] E Left Join  
     ON C.[ItemID] = E.[ReportID] 
GROUP BY C.[ItemID];
```

Comment: Your response was on point. Thank you! +1 from me if I could do it.